# Emails from a SQL Server View

Tags: sql-server, email, reporting-services

Once a week I need to send out emails to a list of users that are in a view. This list will change each time depending on a query (i.e. return all users that have not submitted weekly report).

Is this the best way to do this:

1. Setup mail on SQL Server, as per the [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database).
2. Create a view that looks at the current week's reports and returns the non-submitted users for the current week.
3. Create a SP to send the emails to those in the view (i.e. on friday morning). using some sort of loop and `sp_send_dbmail`

It's a SQL Server 2008 DB. I also have access to SSRS.

Is this the right path to head down or is there a better way?

Comment: You can use SSRS to send reports via email but the recipients must be defined  statically when the subscription is created. However you can create stylized reports from SSRS, create a subscription that generates the report in the format you want (PDF,Excel,CSV) to a folder, then use `sp_send_dbmail` or SSIS to send the file as attachment to a list of recipients from a view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SSIS too, then its far easier to setup a scheduled SSIS job to complete your task and then send email.

Check out the following links for more info.

[schedule a job](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/23/sql-server-running-ssis-package-in-scheduled-job/)

[send email](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

But if you don't have access to SSIS, then sequence of steps you provided seem like the right way to go about your task.